# RxJava - RepeatWhen not cancelling after disposal?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a repeating observable, but when it comes time to dispose of it, such as when I move to another screen, it continues to repeat in the background?

I'm positive it's being disposed of as I've stopped the code and confirmed it's happening.  I'm also positive that it's not being restarted as the function never gets called again once I move to the new screen.

At first I thought it was just going to stop, but after some reading, it sounds like the repeat might be outside of the disposable I'm clearing, so I tried adding that if/else in the repeat when statement.

```
 observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .repeatWhen { result ->
                    if(!disposable.isDisposed) {
                        result.delay((20000 + delay), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    }else {
                        Observable.empty<Int>()
                    }
                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({ result ->
                    //Do something
                }, { error ->          
                    error.printStackTrace()
                }).addTo(tickerDisposables)
```

How do I make this stop when I call call disposables.dispose and switch screens?

Note - The observable is generic type so I need to add a type when doing the Observable.empty()

Update: looks like the problem is somewhere else in my code. The size of my tickerDisposable is empty by the time I try to dispose it, so it's not stopping the calls.  If I find where that is it should fix the issue.

Comment: When / how are you calling `.dispose()`? it all should terminate when you dispose of it. I think you're not calling dispose at the correct moment.

Comment: `repeatWhen` executes its lambda once per subscriber, therefore, your isDisposed check is only happening once when the operator starts running. If you dispose the whole flow via `tickerDisposables`, it should stop the repeat too.

Comment: I'm calling dispose in my fragments onStop.  I can see the call happen.  Then I move onto the next screen (what triggered the onStop) and the network calls are still happening in the background

Comment: Okay, so I did some more investigating, and while I don't have a fix yet, I found that if I put a breakpoint and check the size of my tickersDisposable before it's disposed, the size is 0.  If I check the size immediately after adding it, it's the proper size.  So somewhere between adding it and disposing it, all references to it are being lost so the dispose doesn't stop the call.  I'll have to investigate what might be happening elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure I understand why this resolves the issue yet, but the following resolved it.

Originally my dispose call was happening in onStop(). I noticed that my dispose call worked when I closed the app, but it wasn't working when I launched a new activity.

I tried moving the dispose to my onPause instead, figuring that maybe by the time onStop has called the references in the disposable were lost, and it now works properly.

This might be a side effect of how my repos are set up?  I'd have to investigate further, but that's what was wrong.